# Blue screen crash in Minifilter

Tags: c, exception, windows-kernel, minifilter

I have used minispy as an example to block access to some processes for some files. I am sending the file path and process path to the user-mode application and in user-mode processing is done. Finally, the user-mode application returns TRUE/FALSE, and in kernel mode, if the response is TRUE from the user-mode application then Blocking is done.

`This runs successfully for approx 45min and sometimes 1hr`. And finally the blue screen system crash with an error as **PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA**.

I am unable to figure out why this is happening after some periods of time?

I am lost now. Please help me to identify the cause of this problem.
I will be very thankful to you.

Note: User Mode application takes 1-8 milli sec to respond after processing.

**Minifilter kernel Mode MiniPreRead code:**

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreRead(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Data);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);
    //DbgPrint("MiniPreRead");

    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo = NULL;
    PMINISPY_NOTIFICATION notification = NULL;
    PUNICODE_STRING pni = NULL;

    BOOLEAN isBlock, shouldSkipThisFileName;
    ULONG seconds_to_wait;
    PVOID replyBuffer = NULL;
    ULONG replyLength;
    LARGE_INTEGER timeOut;

    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[260] = { 0 };
    WCHAR ProcessPath[260] = { 0 };

    //update from usermode reply
    isBlock = FALSE;

    shouldSkipThisFileName = FALSE;

    //TODO: How much Waiting Time?
    seconds_to_wait = 5;
    timeOut.QuadPart = -((LONGLONG)seconds_to_wait * 10 * 1000 * 1000);


    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        goto cleanup;
    }
    if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength >= 260) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);

    DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: FileName = %ws\n", Name);

    //skip systm process as fileName: ntoskrnl svchost, & fileType: .sys, .dll
    shouldSkipThisFileName = (wcsstr(Name, L"ntoskrnl") != NULL || wcsstr(Name, L"svchost") != NULL || wcsstr(Name, L".SYS") != NULL || wcsstr(Name, L".sys") != NULL || wcsstr(Name, L".DLL") != NULL || wcsstr(Name, L".dll") != NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;

     //skip if path is not the drivePath
    if (wcsstr(Name, L"Device\\HarddiskVolume") == NULL) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (shouldSkipThisFileName) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    status = GetProcessImageName(IoThreadToProcess(Data->Thread), &pni); //TODO: Improve by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea                  
    try {
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            leave;
        }

        if (NULL == pni->Buffer) {
            status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
            leave;
        }

        RtlCopyMemory(ProcessPath, pni->Buffer, pni->MaximumLength);

        //TODO: skip for system32 process for now
        if (wcsstr(ProcessPath, L"Windows\\System32") != NULL) {
            DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: Skipping SystemProcess: %ws\n", ProcessPath);
            leave;
        }

        //TODO: skip Just for Testing purpose
        if (wcsstr(ProcessPath, L"explorer.exe") != NULL) {
            DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: Skipping explorer: %ws\n", ProcessPath);
            leave;
        }

        DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode:|                                            |\n");
        DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: Final psName: %ws\n", ProcessPath);
        DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: Final FileName: %ws\n", Name);

#ifndef KERNEL_TO_USER
        notification = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, sizeof(MINISPY_NOTIFICATION), SPY_TAG);
        if (NULL == notification) {
            status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
            leave;
        }

        RtlCopyMemory(&notification->ProcessPath, ProcessPath, 260);
        RtlCopyMemory(&notification->filePath, Name, 260);

        notification->msgCountNumId = ++globalCount % 10000000;

        //replyLength = sizeof(MINISPY_REPLY);
        //TODO For both userMode and kernel mode as recommend on doc: replyLength = sizeof(FILTER_REPLY_HEADER) + sizeof(MINISPY_REPLY);
        replyLength = sizeof(FILTER_REPLY_HEADER) + sizeof(MINISPY_REPLY);

        DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: Waiting for usermode reply for MsgSendId: %d,ps: %ws...\n", notification->msgCountNumId, pni->Buffer);
        status = FltSendMessage(MiniSpyData.Filter, &MiniSpyData.ClientPort,
            notification,
            sizeof(MINISPY_NOTIFICATION),
            notification,
            &replyLength,
            NULL);  

        if (STATUS_TIMEOUT == status) {
            DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: timeout occured!\n");
        }
        else if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status) {
            try {
                isBlock = ((PMINISPY_REPLY)notification)->res;
            }
            finally {}

            DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: Reply isBlock: %d,MsgSendId: %d,ps: %ws\n", isBlock, ((PMINISPY_REPLY)notification)->msgCountId ,ProcessPath);
        }
        else {
            DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: --- couldn't send processPath %ws to the user-mode, status 0x%X\n", ProcessPath, status);
            // STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES STATUS_PORT_DISCONNECTED STATUS_THREAD_IS_TERMINATING                                             
        }
#endif 

    }
    finally {
        if (notification != NULL) {
            ExFreePoolWithTag(notification, SPY_TAG);
        }
        if (pni != NULL) {
            ExFreePool(pni);
        }
    }

Blocking:
        if (isBlock) {
            KdPrint(("read file: %ws blocked \r\n", Name)); // only in DEBUG
            DbgPrint(("read file: %ws blocked \r\n", Name));
            Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
            Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
            if (FileNameInfo) {
                FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
            }
            return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
        }

cleanup:
        if (FileNameInfo) {
            FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}
```

`OUTPUT OF` **!anaylze -v**

```
kd> !analyze -v
***************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
***************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except.
Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff8b8e6a20eec0, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000010, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: ffff8b8e6a20eec0, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000002, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 6452

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on DESKTOP-T8VRNB1

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 20375

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 145

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

BUGCHECK_CODE:  50

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff8b8e6a20eec0

BUGCHECK_P2: 10

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff8b8e6a20eec0

BUGCHECK_P4: 2

READ_ADDRESS:  ffff8b8e6a20eec0 Paged session pool

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  2

IMAGE_NAME:  win32kbase.sys

MODULE_NAME: win32kbase

FAULTING_MODULE: ffff8b8e6a200000 win32kbase

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  Registry

TRAP_FRAME:  ffff8185547855b0 -- (.trap 0xffff8185547855b0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=ffff8b8e6a20eec0 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffca0e20ce12c0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=ffff8b8e6a20eec0 rsp=ffff818554785748 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=ffff8185547857f0  r9=0000000000000000 r10=000000004f414f41
r11=0000000000001001 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn:
ffff8b8e`6a20eec0 ??              ???
Resetting default scope

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn+0
ffff8b8e`6a20eec0 ??              ???

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff8185`54785308 fffff804`44c1ebbb     : 00000000`00000050 ffff8b8e`6a20eec0 00000000`00000010 ffff8185`547855b0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff8185`54785310 fffff804`44a0c960     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000010 ffff8185`54785630 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiSystemFault+0x1f43ab
ffff8185`54785410 fffff804`44c03c5e     : 00000000`00000240 ffffca0e`0e968c50 00000000`00000240 ffff8185`547856c1 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x400
ffff8185`547855b0 ffff8b8e`6a20eec0     : fffff804`5eeba14f 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`54785a30 00000000`00000020 : nt!KiPageFault+0x35e
ffff8185`54785748 fffff804`5eeba14f     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`54785a30 00000000`00000020 fffff804`5eecab6e : win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn
ffff8185`54785750 fffff804`5eebaa5d     : ffff8185`547858c8 ffffca0e`00000000 00000000`00004a61 00000000`00000000 : SpyShelter!SpS_GetProcessPathW+0x15eb
ffff8185`547857e0 fffff804`44e0fc1c     : ffffa405`73e28200 ffff8185`547858c8 ffff8185`547858c8 00000000`00000000 : SpyShelter!SpS_GetProcessPathW+0x1ef9
ffff8185`54785810 fffff804`44e0fd8a     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffdc4d`19a20f67 : nt!ObpCallPreOperationCallbacks+0x10c
ffff8185`54785890 fffff804`44e2c20d     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`54785a20 ffffca0e`25e0e050 ffffca0e`25e0e050 : nt!ObpPreInterceptHandleCreate+0xaa
ffff8185`54785900 fffff804`44de1029     : ffffa405`7343d350 00000000`00000000 0038005f`00620075 0079006b`00000000 : nt!ObpCreateHandle+0xa1d
ffff8185`54785af0 fffff804`4395104b     : ffff8185`54786339 fffff804`44b3c67c 00000000`00000208 ffffca0e`25c4c8d8 : nt!ObOpenObjectByPointer+0x1b9
ffff8185`54785d70 fffff804`439512f9     : fffff804`43952be0 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : minispy+0x104b
ffff8185`54785dd0 fffff804`4712608c     : 00000000`00000000 ffffca0e`25c4c7f0 ffffca0e`25c4c8d8 ffffca0e`253efbb0 : minispy+0x12f9
ffff8185`54786280 fffff804`47125b37     : ffff8185`54786400 00000000`00000003 ffffca0e`26747600 00000000`00000000 : FLTMGR!FltpPerformPreCallbacksWorker+0x36c
ffff8185`547863a0 fffff804`47124b46     : ffff8185`54788000 ffff8185`54781000 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`547864c0 : FLTMGR!FltpPassThroughInternal+0xc7
ffff8185`547863f0 fffff804`471248bb     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff804`44e2b3c1 : FLTMGR!FltpPassThrough+0x1d6
ffff8185`54786490 fffff804`44a52f55     : ffffca0e`1f8d0630 00000000`00001000 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`80004210 : FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0x8b
ffff8185`547864f0 fffff804`44dfd878     : 00000000`00000000 ffffca0e`267476a0 00000000`00000001 ffffca0e`0f7ef501 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x55
ffff8185`54786530 fffff804`44de59b9     : ffffca0e`00000000 ffff8185`547867a0 ffffca0e`1c7d16e0 ffff8185`547867a0 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1a8
ffff8185`547865d0 fffff804`44c074b5     : ffffca0e`20ce1910 ffffffff`80004210 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtReadFile+0x599
ffff8185`547866b0 fffff804`44bf98e0     : fffff804`44b18673 ffffa405`86efe000 ffffffff`80001b14 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
ffff8185`547868b8 fffff804`44b18673     : ffffa405`86efe000 ffffffff`80001b14 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
ffff8185`547868c0 fffff804`44ee07ac     : ffffa405`86efe000 ffff8185`54786a58 ffffa405`00000000 ffffa405`86efe000 : nt!CmpDoFileRead+0xb7
ffff8185`54786970 fffff804`44e873fc     : 01d70ea2`09a2a5e3 ffffa405`970df000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!CmpFileRead+0x2c
ffff8185`547869c0 fffff804`44e858a3     : 01d70ea2`09a2a5e3 ffffa405`84d99e20 ffffa405`970df000 ffffa405`84d99e20 : nt!HvpGetHiveHeader+0x7c
ffff8185`54786a00 fffff804`44e8857b     : ffffa405`7626f400 01d70ea2`09a2a5e3 00000000`00000001 ffffa405`970df000 : nt!HvLoadHive+0xa7
ffff8185`54786b50 fffff804`44e88b73     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`54786c90 00000000`00000001 ffffa405`970df000 : nt!HvHiveStartFileBacked+0x107
ffff8185`54786b90 fffff804`44e639e1     : 00000000`00000000 ffffca0e`0000009c ffff8185`54786ee0 00000000`00000000 : nt!CmpCreateHive+0x3d3
ffff8185`54786de0 fffff804`44dd63dc     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`547871d0 fffff804`44e2b3c1 : nt!CmpInitHiveFromFile+0x3a9
ffff8185`54787020 fffff804`44e94ce3     : ffffa405`84d99e20 00000000`00000000 ffffa405`00000000 ffffa405`84d99e20 : nt!CmpCmdHiveOpen+0xdc
ffff8185`54787120 fffff804`44e8cf82     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8185`00000010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!CmLoadAppKey+0x46b
ffff8185`547875a0 fffff804`44e8c77d     : 00007ff8`00000000 ffffa405`7be70580 ffff8185`54787a00 fffffbbf`fc1c5d38 : nt!CmLoadDifferencingKey+0x7f6
ffff8185`54787920 fffff804`44c074b5     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000000b3`33ffe148 ffff8185`54787a80 : nt!NtLoadKeyEx+0x5d
ffff8185`54787990 00007ff8`4510e734     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
000000b3`33ffe1e8 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff8`4510e734


SYMBOL_NAME:  win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn+0

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_INVALID_BAD_IP_win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c8670668-72de-2a31-2f67-c17c5864267c}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

||1:3: kd> lmvm win32kbase
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
ffff8b8e`6a200000 ffff8b8e`6a4da000   win32kbase # (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\win32kbase.pdb\E51C1F9B0FA0D0F8FD417E3DB89E9E911\win32kbase.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: win32kbase.sys
    Mapped memory image file: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\win32kbase.sys\A6BD5AD22da000\win32kbase.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\win32kbase.sys
    Image name: win32kbase.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Image was built with /Brepro flag.
    Timestamp:        A6BD5AD2 (This is a reproducible build file hash, not a timestamp)
    CheckSum:         002CC779
    ImageSize:        002DA000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
```

please analyze this output and help me to get out of the exception. I am completely lost now & need help from the stackoverflow community.
I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: If you [load your pdb in Windbg](https://www.technlg.net/windows/symbol-server-path-windbg-debugging/) you'll get more details (like the exact file and line in your program that triggered the crash). I see no `ObOpenObjectByPointer` in the code you posted.

Comment: @icebp Thanks I load pdb and let you know